# Accessing React childs state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React element that renders Child elements with a `target` state. this target state can change anytime and parent doesn't have access at the moment.

```
const Parent = () => {
  function getTarget(){
    //TODO
  }

  return(
    <Button>get target</Button>
    {children.map(c=>{
      <Child props={props}/>
    })}
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
  //props stuff
  const [target, setTarget] = useState(null)
  // this target would be changed by user as they interact.
  
  return(
    //child elements
  )
}
```

what I'm trying to do is to get the `target` state of the Child using button in the Parent with following restraints:

1. There can be variable amount of `Child` elements, but only one of them are visible at a time.
2. The "get target" button has to be in `Parent`, the "target" state has to be initialized in `child`, and it's unknown.

because only on Child is active at a time, a solution that works for

```
return(
  <Button>get target</Button>
  <Child props={props}/>
)
```

is also fine.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [activeTarget, setActiveTarget] = useState(null);

  const handleButton = () => {
    console.log(activeTarget);
  }

  return(
    <Button onClick={handleButton}>get target</Button>
    {children.map(c=>{
      <Child setActiveTarget={setActiveTarget} />
    })}
  )
}

const Child = ({setActiveTarget}) => {
  const [target, setTarget] = useState(null);
  
  // when the user interacts call 'setTarget' and 'setActiveTarget' to update both states
  
  // update parent state when child mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveTarget(target);
  }, [target]} // you can additionally add dependencies to update the parent state conditionally
  
  return(
    //child elements
  )
}
```

Comment: In this solution I assumed that the child layers each need their own state. So when you show/hide them, they will keep their changes. If this is not the case, the 'useState' within the child layer is not needed.

Comment: yes this worked, they have their own state, it will only change ```display = "none"``` when hid, i have to add condition for which one is active, but this works, thanks.